# Doctrine data type for multiple choices field in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Which doctrine data type should I use for multiple choices fields when creating entities in Symfony 2? for example:

```
        $builder
        ->add('field1', 'choice', array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'choices' => array(
                '1' => 'Option 1',
                '2' => 'Option 2'
            ),
            'multiple' => false,
        ));
```

Comment: Is the amount of choices given and final?

Comment: From Symfony 2.8 on, giving the "simple" field type name like you did, is deprecated. Look at chalasr's answer for how it should be notated

Comment: @LBA Yes choices are given(texts)

Answer (score 2):

For simple data: **array** type

Doctrine relations for **entity** form type